# Setting hotkey to PrintScreen in Jing

Tags: hotkeys, print-screen

I am configuring Jing's preferences.

I'd like to set the Capture hotkey to the PrintScreen key.  However, when I set the focus on the Capture hotkey box and hit PrintScreen, nothing happens.  However, if I do CTRL+PrintScreen it works correctly.  Is there a way to set the Hotkey to only Printscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there another (TechSmith) program installed that uses <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> as the hotkey? (Such as SnagIt or Camtasia (trials)) Jing doesn't allow you to set it if another program is known to use it.

Comment: I do have Gadwin Printscreen installed, but I switched it off.  I'll try again...

Comment: @MikeC You'll have to un set the autokey there too, not just turn it off

Comment: Yep, this was it.  I uninstalled Gadwin and then was able to set the hotkey correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: Fresh installation of Windows 10 and the same problem, nothing more then Windows and maybe onedrive that is bound to this button

Answer (score 1):

Either Windows itself or another program already has the hotkey bound, so we need to override it...

---

Just bind it to another hotkey first, example: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Then use an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script like this to remap <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to that key:

```
PrintScreen::!F6
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  This was my backup plan.